# How to find same elements from two list without turning them into a set?

Tags: python, list

I am making a function that corrects our wrong English words.
but I have a problem.

What I want to do is find common letters from both lists (of words). I know that I can do this using the intersection method of sets but this will remove all double words.

```
wrong_word='addition'
probably_right_word='addiction'
common_letters=common(wrong_word, probably_right_word)
#answer should be ['a','d','d','i','t','i','o','n']  here letter 'c' is not present that's what I wanted.
#  wrong_word & probably_right_word this will remove the duplicate letters so this is not valid answer.

#other example of my problem
list1=[1,1,2,3,4,1]
list2=[1,1,3,6]

result=[1,1,3]
#as shown result is the list of the similar elements in the both list.
```

Comment: Can you show what you have done so far ?

Comment: @KoralpCatalsakal he kind of already did didn't he?  he says he tried using two sets and an intersection and showed how he's calling it.  AJ's solution down there is still basically like using sets, except only for probably_right so (I'm guessing) it's insufficient

Comment: @KoralpCatalsakal  what?

Comment: @RajodiyaJeel can you describe or give more examples of what you're asking for (test cases would probably work best)?  how do you want something like adidtion or naddiont and addiction to behave?  Do you just want it to scan in order?  Or do you want it to find all anagrams?

Comment: That's not clear enough.  Is what AJ posted below what you want?  It matches your comment, but doesn't look like it should fit what you would want.  We don't know your actual use case or what problem you are solving, so we can't infer based on that either.

Comment: @user120242 i added one more example of my problem to the question.  hope you could now understand.

Comment: @RajodiyaJeel what do you want to happen if list2=[1,3,1,6]?  or list2=[1,3,1,1,6]?

Comment: @user120242 result still the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Builds a dict of counts of elements in l2.  Uses that to decide which elements in l1 to include.

```
w1='addition'
w2='addiction'

#other example of my problem
list1=[1,1,2,3,4,1]
list2=[1,1,3,6]

def f(l1, l2):
  l2c = {}
  for i in l2:
      l2c[i] = l2c.get(i, 0) + 1
  # build dict of counts of elements in list2

  res = []
  for x in l1:
      if l2c.get(x,0) > 0:
          res.append(x)
          l2c[x]-=1
  return res


print(f(list1,list2))
print(f(w1,w2))
```

This will achieve what you've asked for, but for real use cases this algorithm should be problematic. I've given examples in my comment above on the main thread of why this could cause issues, which depends on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

```
>>> [char for char in wrong_word if char in probably_right_word]
['a', 'd', 'd', 'i', 't', 'i', 'o', 'n']
>>>
```

Simply iterate through the characters in either word and only add them to the list if they are in the other word as well.